# PostgreSQL query has slow performance due to disk read I/O

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a query in production that takes over 30 seconds to complete.

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=4770.16..4770.16 rows=1 width=988) (actual time=30935.454..30935.469 rows=50 loops=1)
  Output: Extent1".column_g
  Buffers: shared hit=422037 read=44149 dirtied=1149
  I/O Timings: read=28938.746
  ->  Sort  (cost=4770.16..4770.16 rows=1 width=988) (actual time=30935.453..30935.464 rows=50 loops=1)
        Output: Extent1".column_g
        Sort Key: Extent1".column_j DESC"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 113kB
        Buffers: shared hit=422037 read=44149 dirtied=1149
        I/O Timings: read=28938.746
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=105.60..4770.15 rows=1 width=988) (actual time=178.477..30849.677 rows=19053 loops=1)
              Output: Extent1".column_g
              Inner Unique: true
              Buffers: shared hit=422034 read=44149 dirtied=1149
              I/O Timings: read=28938.746
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=105.31..4765.38 rows=1 width=919) (actual time=178.461..30740.970 rows=19053 loops=1)
                    Output: Extent1".column_g
                    Inner Unique: true
                    Buffers: shared hit=364876 read=44148 dirtied=1149
                    I/O Timings: read=28938.312
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=104.89..4760.68 rows=1 width=861) (actual time=178.447..30569.068 rows=19053 loops=1)
                          Output: Extent1".column_g
                          Inner Unique: true
                          Buffers: shared hit=288735 read=44077 dirtied=1149
                          I/O Timings: read=28895.201
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=104.33..4752.10 rows=1 width=348) (actual time=178.433..30430.751 rows=19053 loops=1)
                                Output: Extent1".column_g
                                Inner Unique: true
                                Buffers: shared hit=193456 read=44077 dirtied=1149
                                I/O Timings: read=28895.201
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=104.05..4747.63 rows=1 width=295) (actual time=178.426..30349.064 rows=19053 loops=1)
                                      Output: Extent1".column_g
                                      Inner Unique: true
                                      Buffers: shared hit=140239 read=44077 dirtied=1149
                                      I/O Timings: read=28895.201
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=103.63..4742.23 rows=1 width=237) (actual time=178.411..30145.161 rows=19053 loops=1)
                                            Output: Extent1".column_g
                                            Inner Unique: true
                                            Filter: ((Extent2".column_a IS NULL) OR ("Extent2".column_b = "Extent1".column_b))"
                                            Buffers: shared hit=64027 read=44077 dirtied=1149
                                            I/O Timings: read=28895.201
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=103.07..4699.28 rows=5 width=237) (actual time=178.391..877.247 rows=19053 loops=1)
                                                  Output: Extent1".column_g
                                                  Inner Unique: true
                                                  Hash Cond: (Extent1".column_f = "Extent3".column_a)"
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=3303 read=9522
                                                  I/O Timings: read=496.088
                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table_a Extent1"  (cost=95.33..4688.31 rows=1231 width=237) (actual time=178.289..844.041 rows=19053 loops=1)"
                                                        Output: Extent1".column_g
                                                        Recheck Cond: ((Extent1".column_b = 'f5054190-7100-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) AND ('9'::smallint = "Extent1".column_d) AND ("Extent1".column_e = 'f5054190-7100-00ff-0000-0000000004d3'::uuid))"
                                                        Filter: (NOT Extent1".column_c)"
                                                        Heap Blocks: exact=12491
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=3295 read=9522
                                                        I/O Timings: read=496.088
                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_a_ix  (cost=0.00..95.02 rows=1231 width=0) (actual time=176.095..176.095 rows=19053 loops=1)
                                                              Index Cond: ((Extent1".column_b = 'f5054190-7100-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) AND ("Extent1".column_c = false) AND ("Extent1".column_d = '9'::smallint) AND ("Extent1".column_e = 'f5054190-7100-00ff-0000-0000000004d3'::uuid))"
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2 read=324
                                                              I/O Timings: read=169.848
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=6.35..6.35 rows=111 width=32) (actual time=0.077..0.078 rows=109 loops=1)
                                                        Output: Extent3".id
                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 15kB
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=5
                                                        ->  Index Only Scan using table_b_ix on public.table_b Extent3"  (cost=0.41..6.35 rows=111 width=32) (actual time=0.021..0.042 rows=109 loops=1)"
                                                              Output: Extent3".column_a
                                                              Index Cond: (Extent3".column_b = 'f5054190-7100-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)"
                                                              Heap Fetches: 0
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=5
                                            ->  Index Scan using table_c_pk on public.table_c Extent2"  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1.534..1.534 rows=1 loops=19053)"
                                                  Output: Extent2".column_a
                                                  Index Cond: (Extent2".column_a = "Extent1".column_h)"
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=60724 read=34555 dirtied=1149
                                                  I/O Timings: read=28399.112
                                      ->  Index Scan using table_d_pk on public.table_d Extent4"  (cost=0.42..5.39 rows=1 width=58) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=19053)"
                                            Output: Extent4".column_a
                                            Index Cond: ((Extent4".column_a = "Extent1".column_e) AND ("Extent4".column_a = 'f5054190-7100-00ff-0000-0000000004d3'::uuid))"
                                            Buffers: shared hit=76212
                                ->  Index Scan using table_e_pk on public.table_e Extent5"  (cost=0.28..4.46 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=19053)"
                                      Output: Extent5".column_a
                                      Index Cond: (Extent5".column_a = "Extent1".column_i)"
                                      Buffers: shared hit=53217
                          ->  Index Scan using table_c_pk on public.table_c Extent6"  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=513) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=19053)"
                                Output: Extent6".column_a
                                Index Cond: (Extent6".column_a = "Extent1".column_h)"
                                Buffers: shared hit=95279
                    ->  Index Scan using table_d_pk on public.table_d Extent7"  (cost=0.42..4.70 rows=1 width=58) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=19053)"
                          Output: Extent7".column_a
                          Index Cond: (Extent7".column_a = "Extent6".column_c)"
                          Buffers: shared hit=76141 read=71
                          I/O Timings: read=43.112
              ->  Index Scan using table_b_pk on public.table_b Extent8"  (cost=0.29..4.77 rows=1 width=61) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=19053)"
                    Output: Extent8".column_a
                    Index Cond: (Extent8".column_a = "Extent1".column_f)"
                    Buffers: shared hit=57158 read=1
                    I/O Timings: read=0.433
Planning Time: 38.915 ms
Execution Time: 30935.907 ms
```

We observed that the bottleneck of the query was a join on table_c (using table_c_pk primary key) that took 28 seconds due to repeated disk I/O:

```
->  Index Scan using table_c_pk on public.table_c Extent2"  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1.534..1.534 rows=1 loops=19053)"
      Output: Extent2".column_a
      Index Cond: (Extent2".column_a = "Extent1".column_h)"
      Buffers: shared hit=60724 read=34555 dirtied=1149
      I/O Timings: read=28399.112
```

We are looking to reduce this time, and after investigating a few potential problem areas with no significant luck, we would like to reach out in this forum to see if anyone can suggest areas for improvement.

The following steps were taken to investigate the query's performance:

1. Check for corruption in the table_c_pk index. We used the `bt_index_check` function from the amcheck extension. No corruption was found.
2. Check leaf density in the table_c_pk index. We used the `pgstatindex` function from the pgstattuple extension to detect index bloat. The result:

| index | index_size | internal_pages | leaf_pages | empty_pages | deleted_pages | avg_leaf_density |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_c_pk | 9204695040 | 15996 | 1107543 | 0 | 80 | 3.16 |

The `avg_leaf_density` indicated bloat, so we created a duplicate index on the same column to see how it would perform in comparison. The duplicate index is significantly smaller (33 times smaller):

| index | index_size | internal_pages | leaf_pages | empty_pages | deleted_pages | avg_leaf_density |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_c_column_a_ix | 283271168 | 171 | 34407 | 0 | 0 | 89.9 |

But the performance is still not ideal:

```
->  Index Scan using table_c_column_a_ix on public.table_c Extent2"  (cost=0.43..8.38 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.889..0.889 rows=1 loops=19086)"
      Output: Extent2".column_a
      Index Cond: (Extent2".column_a = "Extent1".column_h)"
      Buffers: shared hit=57105 read=19239 dirtied=417
      I/O Timings: read=16582.408
```

3. Check the autovacuum daemon on the table_c table, as well as check table bloat. We used the `pgstattuple` function in combination with `pg_stat_user_tables`. The result:

| relname | table_len | tuple_count | tuple_len | tuple_percent | dead_tuple_count | dead_tuple_len | dead_tuple_percent | free_space | free_percent | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | n_mod_since_analyze | last_autovacuum | last_autoanalyze | autovacuum_count | autoanalyze_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_c | 8021254144 | 9878802 | 2575180636 | 32.1 | 495703 | 120126243 | 1.5 | 4584097536 | 57.15 | 9881597 | 966903 | 22369 | 2023-03-17 13:32:12.613407+00 | 2023-03-17 18:20:21.469187+00 | 1616 | 3730 |

It was last vacuumed today, and the time before that was 2023-03-16 05:44:47.512332+00.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. We have been looking at the problem for weeks and progress has been slow.

If it helps with the investigation, here is the query (I made sure the table and column references match the execution plan):

```
SELECT "Project1"."column_g", "Project1"."column_k", "Project1"."column_b", "Project1"."column_f", "Project1"."C2" AS "C1", "Project1"."column_l", 
"Project1"."column_m", "Project1"."column_j", "Project1"."column_n", "Project1"."column_o", "Project1"."column_p", "Project1"."column_q", 
"Project1"."column_h", "Project1"."column_e", "Project1"."column_r", "Project1"."column_s", "Project1"."column_t", "Project1"."column_u", 
"Project1"."column_i", "Project1"."column_v", "Project1"."column_c", "Project1"."column_w", "Project1"."column_x", "Project1"."column_a", 
"Project1"."column_b1", "Project1"."column_c", "Project1"."column_d", "Project1"."column_e", "Project1"."column_a", "Project1"."column_b2", "Project1"."column_c", 
"Project1"."column_a1", "Project1"."column_b3", "Project1"."column_d", "Project1"."column_e", "Project1"."column_f", "Project1"."column_g", 
"Project1"."column_h", "Project1"."column_c", "Project1"."column_i", "Project1"."column_j", "Project1"."column_k", "Project1"."column_k", 
"Project1"."column_l", "Project1"."column_m", "Project1"."column_n", "Project1"."column_o", "Project1"."column_p", "Project1"."column_q", 
"Project1"."column_r", "Project1"."column_s", "Project1"."column_t", "Project1"."column_u", "Project1"."column_v", "Project1"."column_w", 
"Project1"."column_x", "Project1"."column_y", "Project1"."column_z1", "Project1"."column_aa", "Project1"."column_ab1", "Project1"."column_a1", 
"Project1"."column_b4", "Project1"."column_c1", "Project1"."column_d1", "Project1"."column_e1", "Project1"."column_a1", "Project1"."column_b5", "Project1"."column_c1" 
FROM 
    (SELECT CAST ("Join6"."column_j" AS timestamp) AS "C1", "Join6"."column_k", "Join6"."column_b", "Join6"."column_f", "Join6"."column_l", 
    "Join6"."column_m", "Join6"."column_j", "Join6"."column_n", "Join6"."column_o", "Join6"."column_p", "Join6"."column_q", "Join6"."column_h", 
    "Join6"."column_e", "Join6"."column_r", "Join6"."column_s", "Join6"."column_t", "Join6"."column_u", "Join6"."column_g", "Join6"."column_i", 
    "Join6"."column_v", "Join6"."column_c", "Join6"."column_w", "Join6"."column_x", CAST ("Join6"."column_d" AS int2) AS "C2", "Join6"."column_a", 
    "Join6"."column_b_Alias2" AS "column_b1", "Join6"."column_c", "Join6"."column_d", "Join6"."column_e", "Join6"."column_a", "Join6"."column_b_Alias3" AS "column_b2", 
    "Join6"."column_c", "Join6"."column_a_Alias4" AS "column_a1", "Join6"."column_b_Alias5" AS "column_b3", "Join6"."column_d", "Join6"."column_e", "Join6"."column_f", 
    "Join6"."column_g", "Join6"."column_h", "Join6"."column_c", "Join6"."column_i", "Join6"."column_j", "Join6"."column_k", "Join6"."column_k_Alias6" AS "column_k", 
    "Join6"."column_l", "Join6"."column_m", "Join6"."column_n", "Join6"."column_o", "Join6"."column_p", "Join6"."column_q", 
    "Join6"."column_r", "Join6"."column_s", "Join6"."column_t", "Join6"."column_u", "Join6"."column_v", "Join6"."column_w", "Join6"."column_x", 
    "Join6"."column_y", "Join6"."column_z_Alias7" AS "column_z1", "Join6"."column_aa", "Join6"."column_ab_Alias8" AS "column_ab1", "Join6"."column_a_Alias9" AS 
    "column_a1", "Join6"."column_b_Alias10" AS "column_b4", "Join6"."column_c_Alias11" AS "column_c1", "Join6"."column_d_Alias12" AS "column_d1", 
    "Join6"."column_e_Alias13" AS "column_e1", "Extent8"."column_a" AS "column_a1", "Extent8"."column_b" AS "column_b5", "Extent8"."column_c" AS "column_c1" 
    FROM 
        (SELECT "Extent1"."column_f", "Extent1"."column_b", "Extent1"."column_e", "Extent1"."column_j", "Extent1"."column_k", "Extent1"."column_l", 
        "Extent1"."column_m", "Extent1"."column_n", "Extent1"."column_o", "Extent1"."column_p", "Extent1"."column_q", "Extent1"."column_h", 
        "Extent1"."column_r", "Extent1"."column_s", "Extent1"."column_t", "Extent1"."column_u", "Extent1"."column_g", "Extent1"."column_i", 
        "Extent1"."column_v", "Extent1"."column_c", "Extent1"."column_w", "Extent1"."column_x", "Extent1"."column_d", "Extent4"."column_a", "Extent4"."column_b" AS 
        "column_b_Alias2", "Extent4"."column_c", "Extent4"."column_d", "Extent4"."column_e", "Extent5"."column_a", "Extent5"."column_b" AS "column_b_Alias3", "Extent5"."column_c", 
        "Extent6"."column_a" AS "column_a_Alias4", "Extent6"."column_b" AS "column_b_Alias5", "Extent6"."column_d", "Extent6"."column_e", "Extent6"."column_f", 
        "Extent6"."column_g", "Extent6"."column_h", "Extent6"."column_c", "Extent6"."column_i", "Extent6"."column_j", "Extent6"."column_k", 
        "Extent6"."column_k" AS "column_k_Alias6", "Extent6"."column_l", "Extent6"."column_m", "Extent6"."column_n", "Extent6"."column_o", "Extent6"."column_p", 
        "Extent6"."column_q", "Extent6"."column_r", "Extent6"."column_s", "Extent6"."column_t", "Extent6"."column_u", "Extent6"."column_v", 
        "Extent6"."column_w", "Extent6"."column_x", "Extent6"."column_y", "Extent6"."column_z" AS "column_z_Alias7", "Extent6"."column_aa", 
        "Extent6"."column_ab" AS "column_ab_Alias8", "Extent7"."column_a" AS "column_a_Alias9", "Extent7"."column_b" AS "column_b_Alias10", "Extent7"."column_c" AS 
        "column_c_Alias11", "Extent7"."column_d" AS "column_d_Alias12", "Extent7"."column_e" AS "column_e_Alias13" 
        FROM "public"."table_a" AS "Extent1" 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."table_c" AS "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."column_h" = "Extent2"."column_a" 
        INNER JOIN "public"."table_b" AS "Extent3" ON "Extent1"."column_f" = "Extent3"."column_a" AND "Extent1"."column_b" = "Extent3"."column_b" 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."table_d" AS "Extent4" ON "Extent1"."column_e" = "Extent4"."column_a" 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."table_e" AS "Extent5" ON "Extent1"."column_i" = "Extent5"."column_a" 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."table_c" AS "Extent6" ON "Extent1"."column_h" = "Extent6"."column_a" 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."table_d" AS "Extent7" ON "Extent6"."column_c" = "Extent7"."column_a" 
        WHERE ("Extent2"."column_a" IS NULL OR "Extent2"."column_b" = "Extent1"."column_b") 
            AND 9::int2 = CAST (CAST ("Extent1"."column_d" AS int2) AS int2) 
            AND "Extent1"."column_c" != TRUE) 
        AS "Join6" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."table_b" AS "Extent8" ON "Join6"."column_f" = "Extent8"."column_a" 
    WHERE "Join6"."column_b" = 'f5054190-7100-0000-0000-000000000000' 
        AND "Join6"."column_e" = 'f5054190-7100-00ff-0000-0000000004d3') 
AS "Project1" ORDER BY "Project1"."C1" DESC  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: what is the query?

Comment: I've added the query

Comment: add the where clause to the joins, that should at least remove a lot of rows, so that the joins will not take that much time, there are still a lot of columns to retrieve,but if you need them all.

Comment: I see the reasoning behind your suggestion. Looking at the execution plan, I believe the query planner already made optimizations on that premise.

Comment: yes, but the query has to be analysed to find optimimasation, but we try to speed things up, that and we tyr different indexes for good meassure

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get an index-only scan.  It looks like your query only references two columns from Extent2, column_a and column_b, so it would be pretty easy to just build an index on those two columns, `(column_a, column_b)`.  Or `(column_a) INCLUDE (column_b)`

Comment: We had previously tried an index on `(column_a, column_b)` to achieve an index-only scan. We observed this did not help our case because table_c is joined again in the query with many more columns selected, which becomes a new bottleneck since the buffers are no longer cached from the first join. Furthermore, there was a substantial amount of heap fetches in the index-only scan (12246 heap fetches, 10382 buffers read), which caused the overall execution time to increase.

Comment: Vacuum your table to get rid of the heap fetches.  It can be a challenge (sometimes) to keep the table well-vacuumed enough, but it is dead simple to do a vacuum once immediately before you run the test.  (And if your bottleneck moves someplace else, then you have a new question with a new plan to share--but it hard to tell what is going on--it didn't help, or it helped so much that the bottleneck is now somewhere else?)